# Intellij idea specify output folder for each source folder (like in eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm working with huge project which has almost hundred plugins which in turn has it's own folder. The issue is that this project was created in eclipse and for each plugin's source folder a corresponding output folder specified. I'm wondering if it is possible to do the same thing in intellij or I'm forced to use eclipse?

Just some screenshots to make thigs clearer:
[image]

Comment: It'd probably be better to manage something like that through the use of Maven or Gradle, honestly. But yes, IntelliJ can do that.  Look under the project settings instead of the general settings, and you'll be able to see your modules.

Comment: @Makoto, that won't be that easy for me to add all these submodules as it contains only build.xml. So no way to import it. As for maven/gradle workaround, seems to be ok. Probably this is the only way out.

Answer (score 0):

In the project structure you can create an artifact for each of your library an specify an output directory.

Try File->Project Structure then in the Project Setting add new artifact and specify output directory